# Is there a way to disallow mongo source connector to register a new schema with Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, avro, confluent-schema-registry

The Mongo Source Connector generates the schema according to the document.  The new schema created for the new document is not becoming backwards compatible with earlier versions of the schema.

[image]

I'm trying to utilize AVRO as a value format, however the connector is attempting to create a schema and failing.

The connector is expected to use the existing topic schema rather than try to override it.

Comment: Well, what changed in your Mongo collection? Is that compatible change? Please show a [mcve] of your dataset (records, schemas, etc). The Connector doesn't know about any pre-registered schema, so will not use "existing" values